# Disabling React-Switch

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and trying to disable the React-switch button which is in a map function. It should be enabled after the user enters keys in the input text field. I am trying to enable it on componentWillUpdate but it says maximum call stack size exceeded.

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state ={
            keyValues  : '',
            tokenValues : '',
            urlValues : '',
            checked : false,
            displayDetails : false,
            disableSwitch : true
        }
        this.toggleFunction = this.toggleFunction.bind(this);
    }
```

this is my local state.

```
toggleFunction = (id ) =>{     
        let data =[];
        let loggedInUserEmail = JSON.parse(localStorage.loggedInUserDetails).email;

        data.push({
            projectId :  id,
            keyValues : this.state.keyValues,
            urlval : this.state.urlValues,
            tokens : this.state.tokenValues,
            email : loggedInUserEmail
        })  

        if(this.state.keyValues !== ''){
            this.props.dispatch(abc(data)) 
        }
    }
```

this is my toggle function.

```
<Table cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="10px" type = 'SETTINGS_JIRA' tableClass = 'settings-jira-table'>
                    {listOfProj.map((item , index) => {
                        return(
                            <Row>
                                <Cell key = {index} cellClass = 'settings-jira-projects' > {item.get('projectTitle').toUpperCase()} </Cell>
                                <Cell> <input type='text' onChange = {(e) => this.setState({keyValues:e.target.value })}  className ='settings-jira-textfield' /> </Cell>
                                <Cell> <input type='text' onChange = {(e) => this.setState({tokenValues : e.target.value})} className ='settings-jira-textfield' /> </Cell>
                                <Cell> <input type='text' onChange = {(e) => this.setState({urlValues : e.target.value})}  className='settings-jira-textfield' /></Cell>
                                <Cell >
                                    <label htmlFor="material-switch">
                                        <Switch
                                            checked={this.state.checked}
                                            onChange ={() => {this.toggleFunction(item.get('projectId'))}}
                                            onColor="#86d3ff"
                                            onHandleColor="#2693e6"
                                            handleDiameter={25}
                                            uncheckedIcon={false}
                                            checkedIcon={false}
                                            boxShadow="0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)"
                                            activeBoxShadow="0px 0px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"
                                            height={17}
                                            width={45}
                                            className="react-switch"
                                            id="material-switch"
                                            disabled= {this.state.disableSwitch}
                                        />
                                    </label>
                                </Cell>
                            </Row>
                        )
                    })}
                </Table>
```

Trying to enable it in lifecycle component

```
componentWillUpdate(){
        if(this.state.keyValues !== ''){
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                disableSwitch : !prevState.disableSwitch
            }))
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add additional checks to compare to the previous state:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  const { keyValues } = this.state;
  if (keyValues !== '' && keyValues !== nextState.keyValues) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      disableSwitch: !prevState.disableSwitch
    }))
  }
}
```

However, it's not the nest idea since this lifecycle method [will be deprecated in the next major React release](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate) and shouldn't be used anymore. Instead you could toggle the switch inside the toggle function or the function, which updates `this.state.keyValues`:

```
toggleFunction = (id) => {
  let data = [];
  let loggedInUserEmail = JSON.parse(localStorage.loggedInUserDetails).email;

  data.push({
    projectId: id,
    keyValues: this.state.keyValues,
    urlval: this.state.urlValues,
    tokens: this.state.tokenValues,
    email: loggedInUserEmail
  })

  if (this.state.keyValues !== '') {
    this.props.dispatch(abc(data));
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      disableSwitch: !prevState.disableSwitch
    }))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried adding the setState in toggleFunction but it doesn't work. Updating in ComponentWillUpdate works but when I enter for 1st Input key filed then all the switches get enabled. I guess this is happening as its in the map function.

Answer (score 0):

when we call `this.setState` method it calls `componentWillUpdate` and that's how your component going in recursive state, If we trigger a state change in `componentWillUpdate()` we will end up in an infinite loop. I think you need better handling of check in `componentWillUpdate`